# Reading accelerometer after screen lock

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, accelerometer

Hi I have an app that reads data from the accelerometer. However after the screen gets locked this not possible.

I have tried the following

```
-(void)startMonitoring{
    UIApplication *thisApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    thisApp.idleTimerDisabled = YES;
        ....
        ....
}

-(void)stopMonitoring{
    UIApplication *thisApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    thisApp.idleTimerDisabled = NO;
        ....
        ....
}
```

How can I keep reading from the accelerometer even after the screen gets locked.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you, you don't want to disable screen locking in general by using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

There is a code sample at github.com playing a sound every x seconds even if the device is in standby mode:

http://github.com/marcop/MMPDeepSleepPreventer

The author just uses a timer firing every few seconds. I haven't tried it out yet, but it should work according to forum posts.

Kay

Comment: Here Marco set up a detailed description: http://blog.marcopeluso.com/2009/08/23/how-to-prevent-iphone-from-deep-sleeping/

Comment: just tried it out. Its still not working. Although the sound plays every 5 seconds I still cant get any data from the accelerometer.

Comment: Strange. Is there any action stopping accelerometer in AppDelegate's applicationWillResignActive method. There is another question dealing with this problem and there it works that way: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529422/enable-iphone-accelerometer-while-screen-is-locked