# Continue to read iPhone accelerometer data while screen is locked (manually)

Tags: iphone, accelerometer, lockscreen

I know this issue has been discussed before as in: [Enable iPhone accelerometer while screen is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529422/enable-iphone-accelerometer-while-screen-is-locked)

I tried the solution mentioned in the post, including adding the   [DeepSleepPreventer module](http://blog.marcopeluso.com/2009/08/23/how-to-prevent-iphone-from-deep-sleeping/), as well as enabling proximity sensor as suggested in the answer [Enable iPhone accelerometer while screen is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529422/enable-iphone-accelerometer-while-screen-is-locked/2539070#2539070) by adding:

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
device.proximityMonitoringEnabled = YES;
```

However, as soon as I manually lock the screen on my iPhone touch, the accelerometer stops sending data. I'm using iOS SDK 4.3. Did I miss anything?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to get accelerometer events on locked ios devices via SDK