# iPhone iOS6 is it possible to run accelerometer while the phone is locked (year 2012 )?

Tags: iphone, ios6, accelerometer

I've been browsing the app store and found 2 examples of commercially-successful apps that boast **being able to run accelerometer-based algorithm with the phone locked** (power button pressed). These apps are "Sleep Cycle Alarm" and "Smart Alarm Clock"

I see quite a lot of Q and A from 2010, 2011 which say that it is impossible to continue using accelerometer when the user locks the device. Yet I see that at least two apps have this feature available.  This is why I'm asking - **is there some new API or workaround that exists as of October 2012 that allows app developers to run accelerometer with the phone power button pushed (phone locked/asleep)? Or is it a secret API that is only available to top-selling apps?**

Thank you for your input! I know there are dozens of questions like that, but I'm looking for the most recent information from 2012.

Comment: @Sharanya: If this is a duplicate question, please flag it as such to be voted on. Do not add the boilerplate duplicate notice by hand.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are no secret api only for top selling apps. Nad i think a work around may be possible to fetch the data of the accelerometer when the phone is in sleep mode or locked.

this link might give you an approach towards your solution check it out

[Enable iPhone accelerometer while screen is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529422/enable-iphone-accelerometer-while-screen-is-locked)

Comment: You see, that answer is from 2010, even before iPhone 4 was released. I'm interested in what suddenly allowed these apps (that presented a screensaver before) to start advertising "full functionality in background mode". This is something new, and I'm trying to figure out what it is