# iOS AVAudioPlayer sound stops playing when screen is locked

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I’ve read *many* articles/posts on this topic, but I’m still unable to play a sound while the screen is locked.

In viewDidLoad, I initialize the audio session and set the audio property to kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback:

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, interruptionListenerCallback, self);
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
AudioSessionSetActive(true);
```

I then initialize my AVAudioPlayer variable (audioPlayer):

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"click" ofType: @"wav"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: fileURL error: &error];
[fileURL release];
```

I added “App plays audio” to a “Required background modes” section of my info.plist.

I added AVAudioPlayerDelegate and AVAudioSessionDelegate to my view controller’s *.h file (although I don’t know if that was necessary).

I play the (very short) sound periodically (~1x per second):

```
[audioPlayer play]
```

The sound plays fine when the screen is unlocked, but stops playing when I lock it. When I then unlock the screen, the (queued) sounds are played.

Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `App plays audio`...? where did you get that string? that is not the proper value for the required background modes...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks holex:

I got "App plays audio" from http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_background-audio/.

If you add a row with UIBackgroundModes to the plist, it's automatically populated and includes this and six other background modes. If you Google "App plays audio" and UIBackgroundModes you'll see plenty of hits.

[I would have replied via a Comment rather than an Answer, but alas, I don't have the reputation.]

Comment: FWIW, here's a StackOverflow post about "App plays audio" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251793/unable-to-create-uibackgroundmodes-key-in-info-plist-for-ios4

Comment: I can tell you the proper value is `audio`, check the Apple official site __every time__: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html, it described very well.

Comment: Xcode populates the list with "App plays audio", "App registers for location updates", "App provides Voice over IP services", etc. If I try to enter "audio" it is immediately changed to "App plays audio"

Comment: Oh, I just opened my plist file using the Pref Setter and it appears as "audio". Xcode must be displaying "App plays audio" and saving "audio". In any case, I think I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is that I'm *starting* to play the sound after the screen has been locked. That's mostly answered in [How to play sounds in locked mode on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913185).