# how to play music using AVAudioPlayer when screen os locked

Tags: iphone, audio, avaudioplayer, background-process

i need to play a simple sound using AVAudioPlayer when screen is locked .How can I do that please help

Answer (score 0):

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749550/sound-and-nstimer-stopped-when-iphone-is-in-deepsleepmode/1767842#1767842) before. As the thing suggests you need to set your audio session as in this example

```
UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
OSStatus result = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                                                                                sizeof(category), &category);

if (result){
        DebugLog(@"ERROR SETTING AUDIO CATEGORY!\n");
}

result = AudioSessionSetActive(true);
if (result) {
        DebugLog(@"ERROR SETTING AUDIO SESSION ACTIVE!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First:** Add following frameworks into your project

AudioToolbox,
CoreAudio, 
MediaPlayer
AVFoundation.

[image]
**Second:** Add your info.plist file a new key

Required background modes = App plays audio

[image]

**Third:** Create a method called keepAwakeForAudio and call it just after playing your audio

-(void)keepAwakeForAudio

{
    UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof (sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
    AudioSessionSetActive(true);
}

//////

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/rain1_Rain_on_Street.m4a", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

```
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([error description]);


else
    [audioPlayer play];

[self **keepAwakeForAudio**];
```