# Continue audio playback when iPhone is locked like iPod App

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, playback, lockscreen

I need to continue the playback even when the user locks the phone. I've seen some solution over the internet, but none of them seem to work, such as:

```
AudioSessionSetActive(true);
    // Set up audio session, to prevent iPhone from deep sleeping, while playing sounds
    UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (
                             kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                             sizeof (sessionCategory),
                             &sessionCategory
                             );
```

I'm inlcuding `AVFoundation`, `AudioToolbox`, and `MediaPlayer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out how to do this.

First of all, include these frameworks to your project: `AudioToolbox`, `CoreAudio`, `MediaPlayer` and `AVFoundation`. Import them all to the viewController where your player will be placed. After you allocated and started playing the audio, insert the following code:

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof (sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
AudioSessionSetActive(true);
```

And finally, go to your app Info.plist file and add a row named `UIBackgroundModes`. The new row will be an array and will contain 1 item, the item 0. To this you just set the value as `audio`. And you're done! Enjoy you're background audio playing app!

Answer (score 0):

Refer following Links:

[How to Continue Music Play after Screen Auto-Lock](http://jomnius.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-continue-music-play-after-screen.html)

[<strike>Playing audio while iPhone is locked</strike>](http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/iphone-development/playing-audio-while-iphone-is-locked/)

[how to play music using AVAudioPlayer when screen os locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706939/how-to-play-music-using-avaudioplayer-when-screen-os-locked)

**Try** :

```
// Set up audio session, to prevent iPhone from deep sleeping, while playing sounds
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;

AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof (sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);

AudioSessionSetActive(true);
```

Comment: I've already tried all these links before and I still can't get it to work.

Comment: @gabriel_vincent try 

// Set up audio session, to prevent iPhone from deep sleeping, while playing sounds
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;

AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof (sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);

AudioSessionSetActive(true);

Comment: Tried it too. Didn't work. I'm placing it after allocating the audioPlayer and before playing the audio. Is it wrong?

Comment: That's all: http://i.imgur.com/V8jlh.png I'm sorry it's a screenshot, but it was too long toa Stack Overflow's Comment

Answer (score 0):

If you have a playlist for example and want to play the next song while in background mode or lock mode add this line of code on your viewDidLoad:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

This makes the app supports remote control events.